# Running apache2 locally without including full path

Tags: apache, apache2, config

I Installed apache server on ubuntu to test my application locally.

The applications hosted on that server are all in the html folder located at the following path `/var/www/html`

When I write localhost, it displays the Index of the folder that are in my html file.

Let's say my application is called application01, to run it I have to write `localhost/application01/src/en/index.html` to the adress bar.

[image]

I want to be able to access it witchout having to include the whole path.

Something like this:

[image]

My apache2.config file contains the following:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I tried to changed the Directory to `/var/www/html/application01/src/`, but it didn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the `Apache.conf` file as it is.
Go to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` folder, Here you will see a file named 000-default.conf. This is the default site for apache.
Open the above file with nano editor using this command `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-defualt.conf`. You will see the document root defined as `/var/www/html` change it to point to the folder of your liking e.g
`/var/www/your-app` then save using `ctrl + o` and run `service apache2 restart` to reload your server then go to your browser and navigate to localhost.
The method above is ideal for localhost because we don't have domains.

in a server setup you would probably need to uncomment the ServerName directive and add your domain name next to itfor example.
`ServerName mydomain.com`

NB You can create as many sites as you want and enabling them with `sudo a2esite site-name.conf` and the restart the server